# Adding new colums in a csv file and values from differents dictionaries-comprehension

Tags: python, csv, list-comprehension, writer, dictionary-comprehension

This is my code below and I would like to write new column in my original csv , the columns are supposed to contain the values of each dictionary created during my code and I would like for the last dictionary since it contains  3 values , that each values is inserted in a single column. The code to write in the csv is at the end but maybe there is a way to write the values at each time i am producing a new dictionary.

My code for the csv route : I cannot figure it out how to add without deleting the content of the original file

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs 
import re
import os
import sys, argparse
import subprocess
import pprint
import csv
from itertools import islice
import pickle
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd

try:
    import treetaggerwrapper
    from treetaggerwrapper import TreeTagger, make_tags
    print("import TreeTagger OK")
except:
    print("Import TreeTagger pas Ok")

from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict

#export le lexique de sentiments
pickle_in = open("dict_pickle", "rb")
dico_lexique = pickle.load(pickle_in)


# extraction colonne verbatim
d_verbatim = {}

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='cp1252') as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        token = line.split(';')
        try:
            d_verbatim[token[0]] = token[1]
        except:
            print(line)

#print(d_verbatim)

#Using treetagger   
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')
d_tag = {}
for key, val in d_verbatim.items(): 
        newvalues = tagger.tag_text(val)
        d_tag[key] = newvalues
#print(d_tag)


#lemmatisation  
d_lemma = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d_tag.items():
    for p in v:
        parts = p.split('\t')
        try:
            if parts[2] == '':
                d_lemma[k].append(parts[0])
            else:
                d_lemma[k].append(parts[2]) 
        except:
            print(parts)
#print(d_lemma) 


stopWords = set(stopwords.words('french'))          
d_filtered_words = {k: [w for w in l if w not in stopWords and w.isalpha()] for k, l in d_lemma.items()}

print(d_filtered_words)     

d_score = {k: [0, 0, 0] for k in d_filtered_words.keys()}
for k, v in d_filtered_words.items():
    for word in v:
        if word in dico_lexique:
            if word 
            print(word, dico_lexique[word])
```

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your code and suspect most of it is irrelevant to the question.  if you could remove details that are not relevant to the question it might get some answers, e.g. a large number of your `import`s don't appear to be needed or are duplicated and a lot of your use of list/dict comprehensions just confuses me

Answer (score 0):

your edit seemed to make things worse, you've ended up deleting a lot of relevant context.  I think I've pieced together what you are trying to do.  the core of it seems to be a routine that is performing sentiment analysis on text.

I'd start by creating a class that keeps track of this, e.g:

```
class Sentiment:
    __slots__ = ('positive', 'neutral', 'negative')

    def __init__(self, positive=0, neutral=0, negative=0):
        self.positive = positive
        self.neutral = neutral
        self.negative = negative

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Sentiment {self.positive} {self.neutral} {self.negative}>'

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Sentiment(
            self.positive + other.positive,
            self.neutral + other.neutral,
            self.negative + other.negative,
        )
```

which will allow you to replace your convoluted bits of code like `[a + b for a, b in zip(map(int, dico_lexique[word]), d_score[k])]` with `score += sentiment` in the function below, and allows us to refer to the various values by name

I'd then suggest preprocessing your pickled data, so you don't have to convert things to `int`s in the middle of unrelated code, e.g:

```
with open("dict_pickle", "rb") as fd:
    dico_lexique = {}
    for word, (pos, neu, neg) in pickle.load(fd):
        dico_lexique[word] = Sentiment(int(pos), int(neu), int(neg))
```

this puts them directly into the above class and seems to match up with other constraints in your code.  but I don't have your data, so can't check.

after pulling apart all your comprehensions and loops, we are left with a single nice routine for processing a single piece of text:

```
def process_text(text):
    """process the specified text
    returns (words, filtered words, total sentiment score)
    """
    words = []
    filtered = []
    score = Sentiment()

    for tag in make_tags(tagger.tag_text(text)):
        word = tag.lemma
        words.append(word)

        if word not in stopWords and lemma.isalpha():
            filtered.append(word)

        sentiment = dico_lexique.get(word)
        if sentiment is not None:
            score += sentiment

    return words, filtered, score
```

and we can put this into a loop that reads lines from the input and sends them to an output file:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
tempname = filename + '~'

with open(filename) as fdin, open(tempname, 'w') as fdout:
    inp = csv.reader(fdin, delimiter=';')
    out = csv.writer(fdout, delimiter=';')

    # get the header, and blindly append out column names
    header = next(inp)
    out.writerow(header + [
        'd_lemma', 'd_filtered_words', 'Positive Score', 'Neutral Score', 'Negative Score',
    ])

    for row in inp:
        # assume that second item contains the text we want to process
        words, filtered, score = process_text(row[1])
        extra_values = [
            words, filtered,
            score.positive, score.neutal, score.negative,
        ]
        # add the values and write out
        assert len(row) == len(header), "code needed to pad the columns out"
        out.writerow(row + extra_values)

# only replace if everything succeeds
os.rename(tempname, filename)
```

we write out to a different file and only rename on success, this means that if the code crashes it won't leave partially written files around.  I'd discourage working like though, and tend to make my scripts read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`.  that way I can run as:

```
$ python script.py < input.csv > output.csv
```

when all is OK, but also lets me run as:

```
$ head input.csv | python script.py
```

if I just want to test with the first few lines of input, or:

```
$ python script.py < input.csv | less
```

if I want to checkout output as it's generated

note that none of this code has been run, so there are probably bugs in it, but I can actually see what the code is trying to do like this.  comprehensions and 'functional' style code is great, but it can easily get unreadable if you're not careful

Comment: When i run the code i have the Following error :      for word, (pos, neu, neg) in pickle.load(fd):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: then you need to make sure your data matches the requirements of the code!  i.e. the above code assumes the `dict_pickle` file is in a specific format, there are lots of tutorials around basics like this